# Django profile not saving

Tags: django-models, lambda

this had keeped me bussy for some time, I hope you can help me.

Context: UserA and UserB are related on some way. In the updateview for the profile of UserA, I also need to make some changes on the profile of UserB but, altough the view runs without errors, the changes on UserB's profile are not saved (changes on UserA's profile do are saved).

My models are something like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ... fields ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



class ManProfile(UserProfile):
    some_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ... more fields ....



class WomanProfile(UserProfile):
    some_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ... more fields ....



def get_profile(user):
    if user.user_type == 'm':
        obj, created = ManProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return obj
    elif user.user_type == 'f':
        obj, created = WomanProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return obj
    else:
        return None



CustomUser.profile = property(lambda u: get_profile(u))
```

Before the view runs both users are like this:

```
userA.profile.some_flag = False
userB.profile.some_flag = False
```

And the view is something like this:

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    ... stuff ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        userB = CustomUser.objects.get(username=self.request.user.profile.friend_username)
        userB.profile.some_flag = True
        userB.profile.save()
        form.instance.some_flag = True
        return super(ProfileUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

After the view runs, the results are:

```
userA.profile.some_flag = True
userB.profile.some_flag = False
```

UserA's profile is saved (which is handled by the form) but UserB's profile is not (although I'm calling `userB.profile.save()`).

If I change the view to something like this both profiles are saved:

```
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    ... stuff ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        userB = CustomUser.objects.get(username=self.request.user.profile.friend_username)
        userB.manprofile.some_flag = True
        userB.manprofile.save()
        form.instance.some_flag = True
        return super(ProfileUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I stopped using the lambda function and instead I called the profile name directly (manprofile in this case because both users are male) and then all is working fine. So, my question is if is possible to call save() on the lambda function and if it is, what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Are you hardcoding the username here or is it an example: `userB = CustomUser.objects.get(username='UserB')`. If it is an example, please replace with the actual code.

Comment: sorry, the example code was because userB is returned fine.

Comment: Instead of `self.request.user` try using the form's username field

Comment: I just tried making changes on the userB object and it work, so the object is returned fine. The problem appears to be on the .profile lambda function. Any ideas?, normally, should I be able to call .save() on .profile (even if .profile is a lambda function)?

Comment: also:

- if I print the fields of userB, or if I  call a method that returns data, I get the expected values.

- I added a print statement to the save() method of ManProfile and now I can confirm that `userB.profile.save()` is been executed, its just the values that are not been saved.

- By trial and error I discovered this:

`userB.profile.save()`: the save() method is executed but the values are not saved.

`userBprofile = userB.profile`
`userBprofile.save()`: the save() method is executed and the values DO are saved.

Comment: The most common reason for this is the `pk` being set incorrectly. Check if the primary key is correctly set before calling `save` and then check if it is correctly saved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the profile called by the lambda function was not cached, so after the asigment, when I called save on the instance, I was actually calling save on a new clean instance of the profile.